# math.random and corona incorrect syntax?

Tags: math, random, lua, coronasdk

I've been doing this for 2 days and getting nowhere.
I want to select 4 balls from the array and randomly drop them, but for the system to remeber and ask for input later.
I'm stuck on the first bit:

```
local ballImages =
{
  display.newImage("ball1.png"),
  display.newImage("ball2.png"),
  display.newImage("ball3.png"),
  display.newImage("ball4.png"),
  display.newImage("ball5.png"),
  display.newImage("ball6.png"),
  display.newImage("ball7.png"),
  display.newImage("ball8.png"),
  display.newImage("ball9.png"),
  display.newImage("ball10.png"),
  display.newImage("ball11.png"),
  display.newImage("ball12.png"),
  display.newImage("ball13.png"),
  display.newImage("ball14.png"),
  display.newImage("ball15.png"),
  display.newImage("ball16.png"),
  display.newImage("ball17.png"),
  display.newImage("ball18.png"),
  display.newImage("ball19.png"),
  display.newImage("ball20.png")
}

function setup()
  math.randomseed(os.time())
end
setup()

local ballImages = ballImages[math.random(4,#ballImages)]
physics.addBody(ballImages)
```

I'm only getting 1 ball to randomly drop. Do I have the syntax in math.random wrong?
Ive tried it several ways but not sure where to go from here.
Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: I see that a lot of your questions are very basic questions about Corona. You should work your way through a couple of tutorials (see for example http://coronalabs.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started-with-corona/). You should also take an in-depth look at stackoverflow's tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour, it's very short but read it all) to understand how the site works and what kind of questions you can ask.

Comment: @VeryNewVeryBad mark this as solved if you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the syntax is wrong. See http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/math/random.html :

> When called with two integer numbers m and n, math.random returns a uniform pseudo-random integer in the range [m, n].

You should make 4 calls to `math.random(#ballImages)`.

If you just want 4 balls, possibly more than once the same ball, you're done.

However if you want distinct balls, you may have to redraw, if you draw a number that corresponds to a ball selected previously. That is if two of your `math.random(#ballImages)` return the same number `i`, that would mean "dropping the ball" `i` twice. If that doesn't make sense, you can do something like the following :

```lua
drawn = {}
local drop=4                                -- how many balls to draw
while drop > 0 do                           -- while we have balls left to draw
    local ball = math.random(#ballImages)   -- draw a random ball

    if drawn[ball] == nil then              -- if ball wasn't selected before
        drawn[ball] = 1                     -- mark it as selected
        physics.addBody(ballImages[ball])   -- "drop" the ball
        drop = drop - 1                     -- decrement how many more balls
    end 
end
```

If your display and physics objects work, then so should this snippet. See here : http://ideone.com/GQC2C6

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. I had a look at the API and if I'm honest I don't really understand it. Do you mean redraw the array?

Comment: All the API says is this : `math.random()` draws random floating point values between 0 and 1, `math.random(n)` and `math.random(n,m)` return integers between respectively 1 and n, and n and m. I will edit to clarify redraws.

Comment: If you could that would be brilliant - I think if I can get my head around this bit I'll be able to continue - its so frustrating! Maybe I need to stop looking at it for 20 minutes :(

Comment: No its not working  - not sure what the problem is. Its just a blank screen now...I'm a disaster!

Comment: @VeryNewVeryBad I had a couple syntax errors left. Try now. If it doesn't work look at the ideone link, it works there.

Comment: How did you do that so quickly?? Its been driving me MENTAL!! Its printing the 4 out randomly - I presume If I want it to display in simulator I just change to display.newImage("ballNumber.png") How long have you been coding? I'm getting bogged down in such simple code I get very aghhhh if you know what I mean!! I don't think I'll ever be able to look at a piece of code and go "oh the syntax is wrong"..

Comment: @VeryNewVeryBad don't worry it comes with experience. To start by the right end, see my comment to your question.

Comment: Its working now - thanks Cimbali. Really appreciate it.